# Can I receive email using the Plesk API?

Tags: email, plesk

I want to receive emails using the Plesk API. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible to tell us what's your real problem?

Comment: Dear experts,I am trying to receive messages from mobile phones using email id. Anyone know about,how to receive emails using plesk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Plesk API for managing mailbox settings. To receive messages from your mailbox, you do not need Plesk API.  You should connect mailboxes through IMAP or POP3 protocols